# Is it possible to use wildcard for Application JAR names in a SparkSubmitOperator Airflow DAG?

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow DAG which I use to submit a spark job and for that I use the `SparkSubmitOperator`. In the DAG, I have to specify the application JAR that needs to be run. At the moment, it is hardcoded to `spark-job-1.0.jar` as following:

```
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


args = {
    'owner': 'joe',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 5, 23)
}
dag = DAG('spark_job', default_args=args)

operator = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='spark_sm_job',
    conn_id='spark_submit',
    java_class='com.mypackage',
    application='/home/ubuntu/spark-job-1.0.jar',       <---------
    total_executor_cores='1',
    executor_cores='1',
    executor_memory='500M',
    num_executors='1',
    name='airflow-spark-job',
    verbose=False,
    driver_memory='500M',
    application_args=["yarn", "10.11.21.12:9092"],
    dag=dag,
)
```

The problem is, the release name will increment and I tried using a wildcard `spark-job-*.jar` but it didn't work! - Is it possible to use a wildcard, or is there any other way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there will always be only one file matching the glob `/home/ubuntu/spark-job-*.jar`, you can do the following:

```
import glob

...

    application=glob.glob('/home/ubuntu/spark-job-*.jar')[0],
...
```